Find the dimension and basis of the vector of the symmetric polynomials
Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials in two variables $x$ and $y$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with degree at most two. That is, $V = \{a_0 + a_1x + a_2y + a_3x^2 + a_4xy + a_5y^2 : a_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$.
Let $V_S$ be a subspace of $V$, where all elements in $V_S$ satisfy $S$, where $S$ is the "variable swap" on a polynomial: it replaces $x$ with $y$, and $y$ with $x$. Find the dimension of $V_S$ and find a basis for $V_S$.
My approach is:Find the terms of $V$ that will remain the same after "variable swapped" regardless of coefficients. I find that only $1$ and $xy$ would satisfy this property, so the dimension of $V_s$ is $2$ and the basis is $\{1, xy\}$. Am I right?

How about $x+y$?

I am not sure whether the linear combinations of the terms are suitable......
I think the prerequisite for x+y to meet the conditions is that the coefficients of the x term and the y term need to be consistent.This violates "regardless of coefficients."

When you selected $1$ in your basis, you put the condition $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=a_5=0$. Then you say for any $a_0$ you can swap $x$ and $y$ and your linear combination does not change. Now let's look at the general case:
$$a_0+a_1x+a_2y+a_3x^2+a_4xy+a_5y^2=a_0+a_1y+a_2x+a_3y^2+a_4xy+a_5x^2$$
For this to be true for any $x$ and $y$, you need $$a_1=a_2$$ and $$a_3=a_5$$
Therefore the subspace contains vector of type $$a_0+a_1(x+y)+a_3(x^2+y^2)+a_4xy$$
The number of coefficients will tell you the dimension of the subspace, and the terms that multiply those coefficients are a basis.

Oh, now I understand. Initially, I only considered the terms 1 and ( xy ) to remain unchanged after variable swapping, but in these special cases, the coefficients of other terms must also be 0. In the general case, there is always a linear combination. Hence, ( x + y ) and ( x^2 + y^2 ) are also suitable.Thanks a lot!

Correct. The entire expression must not change, not individual terms
